# How to bind to the close event of the Infragistics WPF TabItemEx?

Tags: wpf, mvvm, tabs, command, infragistics

I'm developing a WPF project from MVVM way.

I bound Observable Collection to a XamTabControl. And if I add a new item to the Observable Collection a new tab is generated. But if I close the tab, the tab item is not removed from the Observable Collection.

I can do this manually if i can trigger the Closing Event (or Closed Event) for the tab. But those two events are not fired. But some event are fired such as MouseUp.

```
<igWindows:XamTabControl 
 Height="198" 
 HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
 Margin="0,54,0,0" 
 ItemsSource="{Binding Tabs}"
 SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedTab}"
 Name="xamTabControl1" 
 VerticalAlignment="Top" 
 Width="651">

     <i:Interaction.Triggers>
           <i:EventTrigger EventName="Closing">
                <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding TabCloseCommand}" />
           </i:EventTrigger>
      </i:Interaction.Triggers>

     <igWindows:XamTabControl.ItemContainerStyle>
           <Style TargetType="igWindows:TabItemEx">
                <Setter Property="Header" Value="{Binding Header}"/>
                <Setter Property="CloseButtonVisibility" Value="{Binding CloseButtonVisibility}"/>
           </Style>
      </igWindows:XamTabControl.ItemContainerStyle>

     <igWindows:XamTabControl.ContentTemplate>
          <!-- this is the body of the TabItem template-->
          <DataTemplate>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Content}" />
          </DataTemplate>
      </igWindows:XamTabControl.ContentTemplate>

 </igWindows:XamTabControl>
```

And this is my View Model

```
private ObservableCollection<TabItem> tabs;
private TabItem selectedTab;
private ICommand tabCloseCommand;

public ObservableCollection<TabItem> Tabs
{
     get
     {
         return tabs;
     }
     set
     {
          tabs = value;
          NotifyPropertyChanged("Tabs");
     }
}



public TabItem SelectedTab
{
     get
     {
          return selectedTab;
     }
     set
     {
          selectedTab = value;
          NotifyPropertyChanged("SelectedTab");
     }
}



public ICommand TabCloseCommand
{
     get
     {
          if (tabCloseCommand == null)
          {
          tabCloseCommand = new RelayCommand(param => this.CloseTab(), null);
          }
          return tabCloseCommand;
      }
}



private void CloseTab()
{

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's probably because the `DataContext` for the object that runs the Closing event is your `TabItem` class, and not the class that contains the `TabCloseCommand`

Use `ElementName` or `RelativeSource` to set the `Source` of your command binding to the `TabControl.DataContext` first, and it should work

```
<i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding ElementName=xamTabControl1, 
                                         Path=DataContext.TabCloseCommand}" />
```

Answer (score 0):

The code that you have to wire up the closing event doesn't work because there is no Closing or Closed event on the XamTabControl and that is the associated object.  I am not sure if it is possible to use the EventTrigger to attach to an event of the TabItemEx from the xamTabControl.  If you were to add a handler to the XamTabControl without the EventTrigger, you would do the following:

```
<igWindows:XamTabControl 
    Name="xamTabControl1" 
    AllowTabClosing="True" 
    igWindows:TabItemEx.Closed="OnTabClosed">

</igWindows:XamTabControl>
```

You can also see a detailed example in the [Removing a Closed Tab](http://help.infragistics.com/NetAdvantage/WPF/Current/CLR4.0/?page=xamTabControl_Removing_a_Closed_Tab.html) topic in the help.

Comment: Yes. I have bound the command to the tabcontrol not to the tabitem. So I have updated the code but it didn't work.
`<i:Interaction.Triggers>
                <i:EventTrigger EventName="igWindows:TabItemEx.Closing">
                    <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding CloseTabCommand}" />
                </i:EventTrigger>
            </i:Interaction.Triggers>`

Comment: I had tested that before answering and it didn't work though if I add the event the way that I show in my answer it works. I am not sure what the correct way to do this with the EventTrigger is or if it is possible to listen for the event on the TabItemEx when the EventTrigger is attached to the XamTabControl.